# How does dbus calculate the machine ID?

Tags: d-bus

How does DBus calculate the machine ID? (`/etc/machine-id`, `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id`).
Which way is more correct to determine it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The machine ID in [`/etc/machine-id`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html) is usually randomly generated at system install by [`systemd-machine-id-setup`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-machine-id-setup.html). On stateless systems it can also be generated at system boot. The format of the file originates from `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id` introduced by D-Bus.

The `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id` file is randomly generated by [`dbus-uuidgen`](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-uuidgen.1.html), typically invoked by the post-install script of a D-Bus package. It can also be a symlink to `/etc/machine-id`.