# Is machine-id a uuid?

Tags: linux, uuid

I searched my question and none of them answered me:
Is machine-id as unique as mainboard UUID (fetched by
"get csproduct UUID" command on windows)? And is enough reliable to bind a license on machine-id beside mac address?
Or what is uuid on *nix system that can be used for licensing?

Comment: "machine-id" as found where, on what Linux?

Comment: On .../dbus/machine-id file.

Answer (score 11):

## Yes, nowadays.

This is covered in the systemd manual.  The value in `/etc/machine-id` was originally not a valid UUID, because the systemd people did not originally write correct code for generating a version 4 UUID.  But this has since been fixed.

If you bind a licence to the machine ID, be aware that it can change …

- … if someone deletes `/etc/machine-id` and it gets re-created at next bootstrap;
- … if `/etc` (usually on the root volume in practice) is not mounted read-write at bootstrap, `/etc/machine-id` is invalid or missing, and `/etc` cannot be later re-mounted read-write allowing `/etc/machine-id` to be written;
- … if the disc volume containing `/etc` is replaced with another, different, disc volume whilst the operating system is not running or someone changes the machine-id on the disc volume with a tool such as `systemd-firstboot`;
- … if the system is what the systemd people call "stateless" and (effectively, it being slightly more complex than this) `/etc/machine-id` gets re-created at *every* bootstrap;
- … inside containers on the machine.

But it, intentionally, *does not* change …

- … if the mainboard, processor, or NIC is replaced;
- … if the MAC addresses of NICs are changed;
- … if the root volume (more specifically, the volume containing `/etc`) is imaged onto a replacement disc with something like `dd` or `pax`;
- … during system runtime (unless the system administrator deliberately mucks around with it);
- …from one bootstrap to the next if `/etc/machine-id` is valid, non-empty, and writable the first time around.

### portability notes

- Don't use `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id` in preference to `/etc/machine-id`.

  - The original Desktop Bus file which begat `/etc/machine-id` is unfortunately not in a fixed location that is portable across operating systems.  On some systems one finds it at `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id`; on others at `/var/db/dbus/machine-id`.
  - Sometime around 2013, D-Bus was modified to make use of `/etc/machine-id` if it exists, superseding the file in `/var`, whereever it is.
  - In 2015, the Debian/Ubuntu people [made the D-Bus file in `/var` default to being a symbolic link to `/etc/machine-id`](https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/dbus/1.9.20-1), in any case.
- `/etc/machine-id` is not limited to only being available in the bootstrap process after `/var` is mounted or after network interfaces are brought up.
- Although vanilla FreeBSD/TrueOS, NetBSD, and OpenBSD do not provide a `/etc/machine-id`, the nosh toolset provides portable tools (that are also usable on Linux) for creating it that also know of the BSD-specific places that the BSDs expect such IDs and keep the twain consistent.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering et al.. *[`machine-id`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html)*.  systemd manual pages. Freedesktop.org.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`machine-id`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/machine-id.xml).  *nosh Guide*. JdeBP's Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2017). [`/etc/machine-id`](https://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/guide/gazetteer.html#machine-id).  Gazetteer.  *nosh Guide*. JdeBP's Softwares.
- [How dbus calculates machine id?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84777/5132)
- [Why is my systemd journal not persistent across reboots?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/191313/5132)
- [It is OK to change /etc/machine-id?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/402999/5132)
- [Why are my cloned linux VMs fighting for the same IP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/419321/5132)

Comment: The answer to "Is machine-id a uuid?" is as I wrote it.

Comment: Then you were getting mixed up as to what answers what.  (-:

Comment: What do you mean by *imaged onto a replacement disc with something like [...] pax*? Are you talking of the POSIX `pax` (portable archiver) command?

Comment: Something I ran into the other day: cloning a VM means the clone gets the same machine-id. And what makes matters worse, systemd uses it as the DHCP client identifier which means the clone will get the   same IP address as the original.

Comment: You should enjoy the DESCRIPTION and EXAMPLE USERS sections from the new `machine-id` manual page that I just put into the further reading.  (-:

Answer (score 3):

From a quick Google search:

- [/etc/machine-id](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html) should be unique, and only change if the machine is reinstalled, but is provided by systemd, which many systems don't have
- [/var/lib/dbus/machine-id](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-uuidgen.1.html) should be unique, and should be much more widely available.  The [docs](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusMisc.html#ga699a239bc42fd16cca3a17090e49cad8) say it can change if the hardware configuration changes, but in [practice](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/dbus-internals_8c_source.html#l00667) I think it only changes if the machine is reinstalled
- you could use [system-uuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152762/best-way-to-get-machine-id-on-linux), but you need to be root, and it will change if the motherboard changes

`/var/lib/dbus/machine-id` seems like the best method for most situations.

Further reading:

- [On IDs](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/ids.html)

Comment: Which one of them may be useful for licensing? And how to get mainboard UUID on linux?